# sendmessage getting memoryview back .. how to get integer values out?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pywin32

This is what works, the issue is the output

```
tempvar1 = win32gui.PyMakeBuffer(25)
LB_GETSELITEMS = 0x191
temp = win32api.SendMessage(tcwinhwnd, LB_GETSELITEMS, 6, tempvar1)      # Listbox, get Window-Line-index of 6 selected items
result = tuple(tempvar1)
print(result)
```

what Im getting out is:

> (28, 0, 0, 0, 29, 0, 0, 0, 30, 0, 0, 0, 31, 0, 0, 0, 32, 0, 0, 0, 33,
> 0, 0, 0, 0)

how to access that int (28, 29 and so on) direct?

Comment: After making it a tuple why not just take the desired slice? `result = result[::4]` will do the trick, I hope.

Answer (score 0):

The `SendMessage` function is filling in the buffer with the individual bytes of 32-bit integers (little endian). You can combine the individual bytes into an array of ints by shifting and ORing:

```
result = [tempvar1[i] | (tempvar1[i+1]<<8) | (tempvar1[i+2]<<16) | (tempvar1[i+3]<<24) for i in range(0, len(tempvar1)-1, 4)]
```

Or the more succint:

```
result = [int.from_bytes(tempvar1[i:i+4], byteorder='little') for i in range(0, len(tempvar1)-1, 4)]
```

This produces:

```
[28, 29, 30, 31, 32, 33]
```

Comment: thank you very much, almost everything is clarified now, problem solved